# unable to hear 'touchstart', 'touchend' events from trackpad

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying listen to the moment when a trackpad-using user releases their fingers from the trackpad, and more specifically during a two-finger scroll. I basically need this because I want to emulate a you're-trying-to-scroll-beyond-the-border-of-the-webpage effect manually (I have my reasons for wanting to do this, I will elaborate if someone insists), so I need to know when the user "releases" an overscroll, i.e., takes their fingers off the trackpad.

Being a newbie I tried basic things like

```
window.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
    console.log("hello world!");
});
```

or

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
    console.log("hello world!");
});
```

but neither of these events triggers. Other things like `touchmove`, `touchstart` don't trigger either.

Are `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` only meant to be used with mobile devices, not with trackpads?

NB: I am able to listen to the scrolling motion via the `wheel` event. It's just that for my particular functionality, I also need to know when the fingers are lifted from the trackpad, this being the correct time for the view to bounce back into place. (Try overscrolling with a trackpad on any web page, you'll see what I mean.)

Comment: on SO nothing happens if i reach the bottom of the page and keep scrolling :-)

Comment: (not for me... the page scrolls briefly beyond into blank territory, before refusing to go further and bouncing back)